# Excel - Copy to Left if Empty Cell

Tags: excel, copy

```
EXCEL SAMPLE SHEET
     A   B   C   D
1 | 53 |   |   |
2 |    | 5 |   |
3 | 12 |   |   |
4 |    |   | 6 |
5 |    |   |   |  1
6 |    | 4 |   |
7 |            | 55
```

I want to be able to have one column in the end with all the values from COL A-D (except in reality its a lot more columns/rows)

Basically, each row has one value spread across the columns accordingly.  I want to copy into the blank space in the first row with all the rest of the values.  Since there is only one value per row, it will always be blank in any other column.

Final product should be one column list of [53,5,12,6, 1,4,55]

What I've been doing so far is selecting the blank cells and setting it equal to the next col.  But if I do so I have to do it manually for about +50 columns. I was wondering if there was a more efficient method to solve this problem.

Thanks

// EDIT

Purpose of Task

> ```
> COL A                                    | COL B     | COL C
> 1 (Dan, Annotation ID 5)                 | [143, 4]  | 
> 2 (Red shirt man, Annotation ID 143)     | [4, 5]    | 
> 3 (Woman, Annotation ID 2)               |           | [30] 
> 4 (Man, Annotation ID 4)                 | [5, 143]  | 
> 5 (Girl, Annotation ID 30)               |           | [2]
> ```

COL A has a list of all annotations of entities
COL B has first entity (ie Dan) with the list of co-references listed for each entity. COL C the second entity, and so on.  Goal is to have a final column of B to etc. combined. 
(IF this explanation is helpful)

Comment: Did you try the solutions suggested by me or lori_m? Those should both work if your values are numbers as per your example. If the data could be number or text try my edited version.......

Answer (score 2):

If data is numeric you can enter in E1 and fill down this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(1E100,A1:D1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's only 1 value in each row then you could just sum the row, e.g.

`=SUM(A1:D1)`

copy down

Edit: I assumed your data was numeric because that's what you showed in your sample - if not try this variation on lori_m's suggestion

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:D1<>""),A1:D1)`

Assumes data in the range A1:D1, edit as required

Comment: +1: Just as a check you could fill down a COUNT column beside, or alternatively use MIN or MAX.

Answer (score 1):

This works independent of it being numbers:

E1: =A1&B1&C1&D1

This combines all entries and since all but one coloumn is empty you will have the one value you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question.

You want to copy the values of every cell in the table cell, separating the values with commas? And each row will only have 1 cell with a value in it?

I can't think of any way to do this without a lengthy if statement. Could you give a little extra detail on what the purpose of the table is?

Comment: If 10 COL and 50 ROWS, then there are 50 values scattered throughout the columns. Each row can only have one value but each column can have multiple values.  Thus, if you combine all the columns, it will be one column with each row filled out. 

The task is a bit difficult to explain, but it has to do with entity resolution and text analysis.

Each row = annotations of entities, and each column has the equivalent values of those entities co-references... (I feel like this is more confusing?)

Comment: So could you just have the final column be "=SUM(A1:D1)"